# Как можно сделать сайт с таким эффектом

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать сайт с таким эффектом https://www.pinterest.com/pin/695524736186370924/

Comment: День добрый. 1. Каким "таким"? Попробуйте описать словами. 2. В чём у вас именно сложность возникла? Постарайтесь разбить на подзадачи уточнять уже по небольшим подзадачам.

Answer (score 2):

```css
  .text{
    font-size: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    max-width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-height: 500px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }

.b{
  display: none;
}


 .text:hover .b{
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
 }
 .text:hover{
  background-color: black;
 }
.text:hover .a{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <span class="a">text</span>
  <span class='b'>text2</span>
</div>
```